# Why brightness of [UIColor whiteColor] and blackColor are equal

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoa, ios5, uikit

Let my show you some results of getting hue, saturation and brightness of three UIColors.

```
[[UIColor redColor] getHue:&hue
                saturation:&saturation
                 brightness:&brightness
                 alpha:&alpha];

hue = 1.0 saturatino = 1.0 brightness = 1.0 alpha = 0.0
```

> ---

```
[[UIColor whiteColor] getHue:&hue
                  saturation:&saturation
                  brightness:&brightness
                       alpha:&alpha];

hue = 0.0 saturatino = 0.0 brightness = 0.0 alpha = 0.0
```

> ---

```
[[UIColor blackColor] getHue:&hue
                  saturation:&saturation
                  brightness:&brightness
                       alpha:&alpha];

hue = 0.0 saturatino = 0.0 brightness = 0.0 alpha = 0.0
```

Can anyone explain why hue, saturation, brightness of white and black color are equal? Why alpha is equals zero?

What I wanted to do in my project is generate 'darker' color from a given color by changing it brightness:

> brightness = brightness * 0.8;

It works  fine for any color, but it produces black color from white color. (Although I would expect a grey color).

Comment: +1 Great catch, never tried this.

Comment: `saturatino` sounds cuterino :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is because `+whiteColor` and `+blackColor` both return colors in the greyscale colorspace, which is not compatible with the HSB colorspace. As such, `-getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:` is actually not modifying the parameters. I think you'll find you have them all set to `0.0` before calling that method. If you check the return value of `-getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:` it will tell you if it successfully converted to HSB.

Comment: Thanks! So is there any universal way to generate darker color from UIColor, even if it is in a greyscale? Are there any other situation when getHue:saturation:brightness:alpha: may return false?

Comment: @Moriquendi: It's possible other colorspaces may not be convertible to HSB either, but I don't know how many colorspaces you're likely to run into in iOS programming. Worst-case, you can create a 1px-by-1px CGBitmapContext backed by your own data, fill it with the source color, fill it again with a mostly-transparent black, delete the context, and read your pixel buffer for the new color.